# Increase the radius of polygon geometries in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a bunch of polygons in the shape of a pie in a geopandas df under geometry as seen below and I am looking at increasing the radius from x to y of the polygons.

[image]

Can this be done using geopandas or shapely? I am not sure where to start with this. Any help or hints would be much appreciated. Thank you. Apologies for the hand drawn diagram in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas as gpd

data = [[1,72.774906,27.620367], [1,72.983647,27.707941], 
    [1,73.148441,27.785725], [1,73.280277,27.853741], 
    [1,73.401127,27.921714], [1,73.467045,27.795445], 
    [1,73.510990,27.737117], [1,73.521977,27.659298], 
    [1,73.500004,27.581423], [1,73.478031,27.552206], 
    [1,73.467045,27.503493], [1,73.434086,27.454759], 
    [1,73.412113,27.406003], [1,72.774906,27.620367]] 
df_poly = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['poly_ID', 'lon', 'lat']) 

lat = df_poly.lat.tolist()
lon = df_poly.lon.tolist()

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon, lat))
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs="epsg:4326", geometry=[polygon_geom])       


import folium
m = folium.Map([27.6485, 73.2435], zoom_start=10, tiles='cartodbpositron')
folium.GeoJson(polygon).add_to(m)
folium.LatLngPopup().add_to(m)
m
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `shapely.affinity.scale` method.
With this you can scale your geometry in x and y direction according to your desire!
[Shapely affinity scale](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.affinity.scale)

Answer (score 0):

Building on [J.P.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64010159/3364859), I would approach it as follows:

```
import folium 
import geopandas as gpd 
import pandas as pd 
import shapely 

data = [[1, 72.774906, 27.620367], [2, 72.983647, 27.707941], 
        [3, 73.148441, 27.785725], [4, 73.280277, 27.853741], 
        [5, 73.401127, 27.921714], [6, 73.467045, 27.795445], 
        [7, 73.510990, 27.737117], [8, 73.521977, 27.659298], 
        [9, 73.500004, 27.581423], [10, 73.478031, 27.552206], 
        [11, 73.467045, 27.503493], [12, 73.434086, 27.454759], 
        [13, 73.412113, 27.406003], [14, 72.774906, 27.620367]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["ID", 
                                   "lon", 
                                   "lat"]) 

lon = df["lon"].tolist() 
lat = df["lat"].tolist() 

polygon_geom = shapely.Polygon(zip(lon, lat)) 
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs="epsg:4326", geometry=[polygon_geom]) 

# determine the centroid of the geometry 
centroid_lon = polygon.to_crs(3857).centroid.to_crs(4326)[0].x
centroid_lat = polygon.to_crs(3857).centroid.to_crs(4326)[0].y

# plot polygon on map 
m = folium.Map([centroid_lat, centroid_lon], 
               zoom_start=9, tiles="cartodbpositron")
folium.GeoJson(polygon).add_to(m)
folium.LatLngPopup().add_to(m)
m

# scale geometry by 1.5 starting from the tip of the circle segment 
scale = 1.5 
polygon_geom = shapely.affinity.scale(polygon_geom, 
                                      xfact=scale, yfact=scale, 
                                      origin=(72.774906, 27.620367)) 
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs="epsg:4326", geometry=[polygon_geom]) 

# determine the centroid of the geometry 
centroid_lon = polygon.to_crs(3857).centroid.to_crs(4326)[0].x
centroid_lat = polygon.to_crs(3857).centroid.to_crs(4326)[0].y

# plot polygon on map 
m = folium.Map([centroid_lat, centroid_lon], 
               zoom_start=9, tiles="cartodbpositron")
folium.GeoJson(polygon).add_to(m)
folium.LatLngPopup().add_to(m)
m
```

**But beware**: `shapely.affinity.scale` scales on the x and y axis! Strictly speaking, you cannot redefine the radius of the circle segment that your polygon happens to resemble. Therefore, the polygons will probably not be congruent, see screenshot below.

[image: screenshot of Jupyter notebook with code]